# Redirecting Standard Output to Current Console in Go Using CreateProcessWithTokenW

Tags: windows, go, cmd, console

I'm working with Go and trying to launch a new CMD shell using `CreateProcessWithTokenW`. My goal is to redirect the standard output to the current console window so that I can run commands from the same window.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
func launchCmd(token windows.Token) {
    var si windows.StartupInfo
    var pi windows.ProcessInformation

    // Duplicate the handles
    dupStdin, err := duplicateHandle(os.Stdin.Fd())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error duplicating stdin handle:", err)
        return
    }
    dupStdout, err := duplicateHandle(os.Stdout.Fd())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error duplicating stdout handle:", err)
        return
    }
    dupStderr, err := duplicateHandle(os.Stderr.Fd())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error duplicating stderr handle:", err)
        return
    }

    defer windows.CloseHandle(dupStdin)
    defer windows.CloseHandle(dupStdout)
    defer windows.CloseHandle(dupStderr)

    si = windows.StartupInfo{
        Cb:        uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(si)),
        Flags:     windows.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES,
        StdInput:  dupStdin,
        StdOutput: dupStdout,
        StdErr:    dupStderr,
    }

    err = CreateProcessWithTokenW(
        token,
        0,
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        &si,
        &pi,
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error CreateProcessWithTokenW:", err)
        return
    }

    defer windows.CloseHandle(pi.Process)
    defer windows.CloseHandle(pi.Thread)

    fmt.Printf("Launched cmd.exe with PID: %d\n", pi.ProcessId)
    windows.WaitForSingleObject(pi.Process, windows.INFINITE)
    fmt.Println("Process completed.")
}

func duplicateHandle(fd uintptr) (windows.Handle, error) {
    var dupHandle windows.Handle
    procHandle := windows.CurrentProcess()
    err := windows.DuplicateHandle(procHandle, windows.Handle(fd), procHandle, &dupHandle, 0, true, windows.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("error duplicating handle: %w", err)
    }
    return dupHandle, nil
}

func CreateProcessWithTokenW(duplicatedToken windows.Token, creationFlags uint32, commandLine string, startupInfo *windows.StartupInfo, processInfo *windows.ProcessInformation) error {
    cmdPtr, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(commandLine)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    r1, _, e1 := syscall.SyscallN(
        procCreateProcessWithTokenW.Addr(),
        uintptr(duplicatedToken),
        0,
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(cmdPtr)),
        uintptr(creationFlags),
        0,
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(startupInfo)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(processInfo)),
    )
    if r1 == 0 {
        return e1
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, this code doesn't achieve what I want. Instead, it opens a new CMD window where I can run commands, but it's separate from my current console.

For comparison, when I use the following code with `exec.Command`, it works as intended and keeps the output in the same console:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe")
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

I'm looking to replicate this behavior but using `CreateProcessWithTokenW` instead. How can I modify my current approach to redirect the standard output to the same console window?